# How to resolve a rebase conflict when file was removed from master?

Tags: git, rebase, git-merge-conflict

From `master`, the `A` branch was branched. Then, a few commits (to `master`) later, `B` branch was branched.

The owner of `A` made changes to file `fname`. The owner of `B` removed `fname` altogether.

Then, `B` was rebased and merged into `master`. Now, `A` is to be rebased and merged. But now `A`'s owner gets a conflict with file `fname`, saying that:

`CONFLICT (modify/delete): fname deleted in HEAD and modified in "commit msg". Version "commit msg" of fname left in tree.`

Normally, conflicts are resolved by editing the intermediate file, `git add fname` it and then `git rebase --continue` the process.

But how to resolve a conflict of a removed file? The end result should be that the files is removed.

Comment: Did you try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5516391/git-rebase-will-not-continue-after-a-delete-modify-conflict

Comment: @wcarhart - Thanks.  If I understand correctly, then the recommendation is to `git rm fname` then `git add -A`. But isn't `add -A` and all-inclusive command? What if I have multiple conflicts (some of then are of the nature described in the question, some not), and I want to resolve them one-by-one? Or, if I have untracked files in the repo directory?

Comment: `-A` will be all inclusive, but you can do `git rm fname` and then `git add <file>` individually for each change you want to keep. Does that work?

Comment: @wcarhart - unfortunately, not. This was the 1st thing I tried. Got an error: `fatal: pathspec 'fname' did not match any files`

Comment: Hmm, maybe take a look at this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25458306/git-rm-fatal-pathspec-did-not-match-any-files/25458504

Comment: @wcarhart - don't think so. The question describes a different situation and the answers resolve a different problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case you can just delete the file not with `git rm` but just with `rm`.

```
rm fname
git add fname
#Fix any other conflict
git rebase --continue
```

Whichever way you leave your file it will be used in the new commit that is being generated.

---

**What's going on:**

1. The rebase was interrupted because of a conflict.
2. If you check the log, your current HEAD is the head of `master`.
3. You have a file that does not exist in this HEAD. That means that you can't ask `git rm` because that file is not under version control.
4. We just remove the file as if you would do with a new file that you don't want to commit.

---

If the only change in the current commit was on this deleted file you'll get this error:

```
`No changes - did you forget to use 'git add'?`
```

This is because there is nothing to commit (You have just deleted a file that did not exist in git) In that case you can `git rebase --skip` instead of `--continue`.